# Shopify enter password field

Tags: passwords, shopify

I am creating my Shopify store right now, and I don't know how to add 'enter password' field on password page. I tried many codes that I've found in internet, but nothing has worked as for now. 
Could anybody please help me?

Comment: It's not clear what password page do you mean? Activate Account on inviting customers or Reset Password when a customer is trying to recover his account?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question seems not clear,

However you might be facing issue to enable customer registration.

if yes follow below step:

Go to Settings => Checkout

And check below option as shown in the screenshot.

[image]